# How to return associative array type out parameter from oracle procedure

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, associative

I am trying to execute a procedure that has an associative array as one of the out parameters.  I keep getting an error saying wrong number or types of arguments in call to put_line.

I have tried to setup a variable with the same type and use that in the call to the procedure that is returning the associative array.

```
DECLARE

P_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(4000);
P_FUSION_CC KPE_COA_VALUE_LOOKUP_PKG.P_FUSION_CC_TBL;
--v_fusion KPE_COA_VALUE_LOOKUP_PKG.P_FUSION_CC_TBL;

BEGIN

KPE_COA_VALUE_LOOKUP_PKG.GET_FUSION_CC('EBS 
COA','001:0069:274000:05045:038:000000',':',P_MESSAGE,P_FUSION_CC); 

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_fusion_cc);

END;
```

I get this error PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'

Answer (score 2):

Accessing key value pairs of an associative array in PL/SQL or printing for that matter is not straightforward and should use a specific sequence of loop.

Here's an illustration

```
declare
   type assoc_array_typ is table of varchar2(30) index by varchar2(30);

   l_assoc_array assoc_array_typ;
   l_idx varchar2(30);
begin
   l_assoc_array('First_name')   := 'Narendra';
   l_assoc_array('middle_name')  := 'Damodardas';
   l_assoc_array('Last_name')    := 'Modi';

   ---To print the array
   l_idx := l_assoc_array.first;
   while (l_idx is not null) loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Key = ' || l_idx || ',
                          Value = ' || l_assoc_array(l_idx));
      l_idx := l_assoc_array.next(l_idx);
   end loop;
   ---End printing
end;
/
```

Output

```
Key = First_name, Value = Narendra
Key = Last_name, Value = Modi
Key = middle_name, Value = Damodardas


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

The deceleration indicates it takes a String argument.  Looks like you're attempting to pass the entity array. You can't do that. You'll need to pass individual elements from the array.

```
 dbms_output.put_line(p_fusion_cc.column1 || ' ' || p_fusion_cc.column2  ... );
```